# How do I add a list item back to the nested elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I have a menu that I would to remove and add list items to.  I’ve been successful at removing items but I can’t seem to use the add method correctly.  Say my menu looks like this:

```
<nav>
    <ul id="menu" >
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Teachers", "Index", "Instructor")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Students", "Index", "Student")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Courses", "Index", "Course")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Departments", "Index", "Department")</li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Parent</a>
            <ul>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Parent", "Index", "Department")</li>
                <li id="std">@Html.ActionLink("Student", "Index", "Department")</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

In my script I stored the object like this:

```
var savedLi = $("#std");
```

and I can remove it like this:

```
$(savedLi).remove();
```

Now I’m trying to replace it to it’s original position like this:

```
var replaceId=$(“nav ul li ul li”);

$(savedLi).add(replaceId);
```

How do I add my list item back to the nested elements?

Comment: try  savedLi.append(replaceId);

Comment: you misunderstood the use of the `add` method, it's not some counterpart of `remove`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's opposite, you should use this: `replaceId.append(savedLi);`

Updated:
And the selector should be

```
var replaceId=$(“nav ul li ul”);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `add()` method is used to add the given element to existing object (collection) you probably need to use append or html()

```
savedLi.append(replaceId);
```

> Add(): Add elements to the set of matched elements.

Comment: i am not the dvr.. but i dont thing .append() will not work as expected right..?

Comment: He seems to add replaceId to savedLi by $(savedLi).add(replaceId);